# BigCommerce StoreFront API SSO - Invalid login. Please attempt to log in again

Tags: bigcommerce

Been at this for a few days. I am making a login form on my angular/nodejs app. The bc-api is able to verify the user/password. Now with that i need to allow the customer to enter the store with sso but the generated jwt is not working. My attempt below... I am looking for troubleshooting tips.

## Generate JWT / sso_url

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}

function get_token(req, data) {
    let uid = req.id;
    let time = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    let  payload = {
        "iss": app.clientId,
        // "iat": Math.floor(new Date() / 1000),
        "iat": time,
        "jti": uid+"-"+time,
        "operation": "customer_login",
        "store_hash": app.storeHash,
        "customer_id": uid,
        "redirect_to": app.entry_url
    }
    let token = jwt.encode(payload, app.secret, 'HS512');
    token = decode_utf8(token);
    let sso_url = {sso_url: `${app.entry_url}/login/token/${token}`}
    return sso_url
}
```

## `payload` resolves to

```
{
    "iss": "hm6ntr11uikz****l3j2o662eurac9w",
    "iat": 1529512418,
    "jti": "1-1529512418",
    "operation": "customer_login",
    "store_hash": "2bihpr2wvz",
    "customer_id": "1",
    "redirect_to": "https://store-2bihpr2wvz.mybigcommerce.com"
}
```

## generated `sso_url`

```
https://store-2bihpr2wvz.mybigcommerce.com/login/token/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJobTZudHIxMXVpa3oxMXpkbDNqMm82NjJldXJhYzl3IiwiaWF0IjoxNTI5NTEyNDE4LCJqdGkiOiIxLTE1Mjk1MTI0MTgiLCJvcGVyYXRpb24iOiJjdXN0b21lcl9sb2dpbiIsInN0b3JlX2hhc2giOiIyYmlocHIyd3Z6IiwiY3VzdG9tZXJfaWQiOiIxIiwicmVkaXJlY3RfdG8iOiJodHRwczovL3N0b3JlLTJiaWhwcjJ3dnoubXliaWdjb21tZXJjZS5jb20ifQ.vaeVTw4NjvX6AAPChgdXgMhm9b1W5B2QEwi4sJ6jz9KsKalqTqleijjRKs8jZP8jdQxC4ofYX5W0wYPMTquxQQ
```

## result

[image]

## about my env

I am using nodejs express... my bc app's secret & clientId are being used above and they work for several other bc-api tasks. My app is installed and authenticated on bc admin. The app being used to do the above is running on localhost but i also tried online https (same result).

I am thinking that there might be some incorrect configuration in my stores admin but havent found anything to change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decoded your JWT on jwt.io and I get this:

**Header:**

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS512"
}
```

There's at least one problem here

- BC requires HS256 as the algorithm according to docs

  https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/storefront.html#/introduction/customer-login-api

**Body:**

```
{
  "iss": "hm6ntr11uikz11zdl3j2o662eurac9w",
  "iat": 1529512418,
  "jti": "1-1529512418",
  "operation": "customer_login",
  "store_hash": "2bihpr2wvz",
  "customer_id": "1",
  "redirect_to": "https://store-2bihpr2wvz.mybigcommerce.com"
}
```

Problems here:

- JTI should be a totally random string, using something containing the time could result in duplicates which will be rejected. Try using a UUID
- Customer ID should be an int, not a string
- The redirect_to parameter accepts relative URLs only. So try **"redirect_to": "/"** if your goal is to redirect to the home page.
- Another *potential* problem is system time - if your JWT was created in the "future" according to BC's server time, your JWT also won't work. You can use the /v2/time endpoint response to specify the IAT, or to keep your own clock in sync.

Comment: Dang I had that in another version and missed it when I re-wrote it. Thank you. It works now.